# Thread messaging or better: Accessing members from other class in "master-class"

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, inheritance

- *First of all: Sorry for the probably bad title and that many text - this is because I'm trying to describe my problem as exact as possible! :)*

  - If my principle idea is unclear please add a comment - I will try to rewrite the question (since English isn't my mother's tongue).
  - If there is even a better approach of doing this, I would also glad if you would share your ideas with me!

**Background**

I'm currently working on a messaging system in C++ for interaction between threads. 
The principle idea is to haven a class - let’s call them `SharedMessage` that holdas my message data. After assigning values I want to add them to a queue so my threads can work with the informations stored in these messages.

The problem is, that the content of the messages depends on its type. E. g. there are multiple "message types" but all these different types should be held in the same queue (e. g. `messages`).

---

**First/Simplest Idea**

The simplest approach I was thinking about, was just adding a list `args_string_` as a member variable to my `SharedMessage`-class and accessing the list’s content by using getter and setter. To distinguish between the different message types I was using another member variable called `messageType`.
Here is an example:

```c
class SharedMessage{
public: 
  void setMessageType(int type)(); // sets the message type
  void addArg(std::string arg)(); // add an item to the list
  void getArgs(); // Should return the list args_string_
private:
 int messageType = 1;
 std::vector<string> args_string_;
};
```

Now I'm just populating my class's list, assign a *messageType* and afterwards add them to my queue. My threads can access and delete them from my queue (queue `messages`).

The problem: This is not a very elegant way. I always need to know in which order my arguments needs to be processed.

---

**My hypothetical idea:**

Because of the problem described above, I was more thinking about something like using kind of *templates* or *inheritances*. I don't know if there is something similar – e. g. dynamically inherit from other classes.

Let’s have a look at my ideas I was thinking of:

In this case I again got my `SharedMessage`-class – but now I do not add any members. This is because I want to defined members later at runtime/instantiation/compilation (is this even possible?) – maybe the same way the STL-Class is doing this.

```c
// This should be my "master"-class. The queue should be able to hold elements of this type.
class SharedMessage 
{ };
```

Now I got two “dummy” commands: `Command1`, `Command2`

```c
// This is one possible command that can hold a string ("command1")
// They can be accessed by using getters/setters
class Command1{
  std::string command1;
  void setCommand1(std::string cmd1);
  std::string getCommand1();
}

// Second possible command. Note that in this case my command holds an integer ("counter")
class Command2{
  double counter;
  void setCounter(int cnt);
  int getCounter();
}
```

These commands have different members.
The idea is now using something like the following code. In my `main` I’m create the mentioned queue `messages` that can hold instances of type *SharedMessage*.
And now this is where it gets interesting. I want to be able to do something like this. Instciate a  `SharedMessage` but with the *inherited* members from `Command1` (maybe something like`SharedMessage<Command1> sharedmessage;`?)
Afterwards I can use these members from `Command1`, besides `sharedmessage` is of type `SharedMessage`!

*(In this is how I want to access the members?!)*
E. g.:

```c
main() {
// This is my queue.
queue <SharedMessage> messages; 

// I want to create a Shared message of type Command1
SharedMessage<Command1> sharedmessage;

// This is the interesting line. Is there a function for this dynamic "member generation". Like inheritance (but in a dynamic way/like templates)?
sharedmessage.setCommand1("My command); // I’m using Command1 member beside “sharedmessage” is of datatype “SharedMessage”
// Add to queue
messages.push(sharedmessage);

// And this should also work :
SharedMessage<Command2> sharedmessage2;
message.setCounter(172);
// Add second message with different content to queue
messages.push(sharedmessage);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inheritance, if you make your queue store pointers to messages. It would look like this:

```
class SharedMessage {...};
class Command1: public SharedMessage {...};
class Command2: public SharedMessage {...};
...
std::queue<SharedMessage *> messages;
Command1 message1;
Command2 message2;
messages.push(&message1);
messages.push(&message2);
```

The drawback is that your queue now no longer stores the messages themselves, just pointers, so you'd need some way to manage their lifetime. A possibility would be to use `std::queue<std::unique_ptr<SharedMessage>>`, and add messages to the queue like so:

```
messages.push(std::make_unique<Command1>());
// or:
auto message2 = std::make_unique<Command2>();
messages.push(std::move(message2));
```

To get a message out of a queue, write something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<SharedMessage> message = std::move(messages.front());
messages.pop();
```

You can't use templates like in your last example, since if you have `template<typename T> class SharedMessage {...}`, then `std::queue<SharedMessage>` does not compile, since `SharedMessage` alone is not a real type. You could make a `std::queue<SharedMessage<Command1>>`, but then of course you couldn't use it to store a `SharedMessage<Command2>` in.

Comment: I also thought about the idea you pointed out (I've even implemented it before) but I didn’t used ```unique_ptr```. Because of the lack of other options, I will try to implement the idea of using ```unique_ptr```.